# Matching Special character '-' using Regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string `p9909abc0221-` and `p9909abc0221` I have written regular expression to match the user input and validating it .The String may or may not contain '-' spcial character in last .

Using the below code

```
return (str !== undefined && str.match('^(P|p)[0-9]{4}(ABC|abc)[0-9]{4}[/-]$'));
```

I think I am doing wrong for '-' special character . Any help would be great

Comment: It's not a special character, only inside a character class to define a range. Just use it like you would other characters (i.e., `-` instead of `[/-]`. Additionally, you probably tried to escape it by doing what you did, but you need the backslash for that; `[\-]` is possible. And since the `-` is apparently optional, use `-?`.

Comment: As an aside comment, you must put your pattern between delimiters `/` without quotes: `str.match(/^(P|....$/)`

Answer (score 1):

Some problems here:

- regexes are not strings, use `/.../`, not `'...'`
- instead of `(ABC|abc)` just make the pattern case-insensitive (unless you want to disallow `Abc`)
- `[\-]` is just the same as `-`
- `\d` is a shortcut for `[0-9]`

That is,

```
return (str !== undefined && str.match(/^p\d{4}abc\d{4}-?$/i));
```

or

```
return (str !== undefined && str.match(/^[Pp]\d{4}(ABC|abc)\d{4}-?$/));
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `-?` to indicate `-` may appear no more than once
- `[/-]` does not make sense

This should work:

```
^(P|p)[0-9]{4}(ABC|abc)[0-9]{4}-?$
```

Answer (score 0):

If the '-' char may or may not be contained you need to use '?'

So your regex needs to be like this:

```
^(P|p)[0-9]{4}(ABC|abc)[0-9]{4}-?$
```

You can try regex on:
http://regex101.com/r/cU5oK8

Answer (score 0):

Based on the two examples you provided, this works for me:

```
str.match(/p\d{4}abc\d{4}-?/i)
```

Updated, based on comment below.

Comment: His second example is ok, it was my sloppy edit that killed a char. BTW, you might want to add anchors to your expr, since the question is about validation.